# Subtyping polymorphism in Coq

Tags: types, polymorphism, coq

I want to define a weighted tree with variable fan-out which is polymorphic over types. I came up with this:

```
(* Weighted tree with topological ordering on the nodes. *)
Inductive wtree (A : Type) : Type :=
  LNode : A->wtree A
| INode : A->list (R*wtree A) -> wtree A.
```

However, I would prefer to store the weight in a type, something like:

```
Inductive Wtype (A : Type) : Type := W : R->A->Wtype A.
Inductive wtree (A : Wtype) : Type :=
  LNode : A->wtree A
| INode : A->list (wtree A) -> wtree A.
```

where `R` is the set of real numbers from the standard library.

This doesn't work becuase `Wtype` is a `Type->Type`, not a `Type`, but I can't figure out how to do this. Unfortunately I still live in Object Oriented land and I really just want to give a more restrictive super type to `A` than `Type`, but just can't figure out how to do it in Coq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Wtype` is `Type -> Type` yes? Since we can't not apply it, we need to give it some sort of argument. So we need to apply it to some argument. A simple solution to this might be just

```
Inductive wtree' (A : Type) : Type :=
| LNode : A -> wtree' A
| INode : A -> list (wtree' A) -> wtree A.

Inductive Wtype (A : Type) : Type := W : R -> A -> Wtype A.

Definition wtree (A : Type) := wtree' (Wtype A).
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess i have solved this with:

```
Inductive Wtype (A : Type) : Type := W : R->A->Wtype A.

Inductive wtree (A : Type) : Type :=
  LNode : Wtype A->wtree A
| INode : Wtype A->list (wtree A) -> wtree A.
```

However, it seems like it would be nicer to just be able to say something more like `Inductive wtree (A : WType) ...` and avoid cluttering up definition with lots of "`Wtype A`"'s all throughout the definition.